# Exit the SQLite shell on Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite 3 on Mac OS X's [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_Debug_Bridge_(ADB)) shell to view my application database using:

```
#sqlite3 mydb.db
SQLite version 3.5.9
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> quit
...> .quit
...>
```

After I wrongly typed the `quit` command above, instead of the `.quit` for example, the shell goes into the `...>` prompt where none of the known commands seem to work. I can't even get out by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, etc.

I have to <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> i.e. quit the terminal instance to restart. I know this isn't exactly a programming question, but it really is annoying enough for me to write here.

How can I restore sanity to the terminal after such errors without relaunching the terminal?

Comment: Is there an earlier duplicate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type <kbd>;</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This might fix it. This works for other SQL stuff.

Comment: Sometimes `;` doesn't fix it. In that case try `CTRL+\\`, it seems to work most of the time.

Comment: I have a similar question and this solution doesn't work as intended. I would like to create a table and insert a few rows, but as soon as I press insert the prompt turns into ...> and I can't figure out how to change it. If I use CTRL Z it does quit, but it quits sqlite completely and erases the table. How do you just create a table from the terminal?

Comment: Type your entire query then use the `;` at the end of your query. Not exactly sure i understand your problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask a new question on stackoverflow.com to have more eyes see it.

Comment: @CodePoet, CTRL+Z only suspends sqlite3. Your earlier answer of CTRL+\ is interpreted as \Quit and properly terminates the program for me.

Answer (score 17):

You have just to type

```
sqlite> .exit
```

Answer (score 5):

You can even try this

- For Windows

  > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
- For a Unix terminal

  > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

(It sends [end of file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) to standard input.)