# Exit a SQLite 3 database

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite 3 database in SUSE Linux.

It's stuck at the command prompt like so:

```
sqlite> q
   ...> exit
   ...> .exit
   ...> quit
   ...> .quit
```

How do I exit out of the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Exit the SQLite shell on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648652/exit-the-sqlite-shell-on-android)*. Despite the specifics it is the general question.

Comment: Use keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+D

Answer (score 146):

Type <kbd>;</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to terminate the current statement (will give an error message because what you typed so far is not a valid statement but never mind). Then `.quit` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note that in SQLite 3, SQL statements must be terminated with a delimiter, which is `;` by default. The non-SQL commands, which start with a `.`, do not need to be terminated this way, but they are considered complete as soon as <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

If a command does not start with a `.` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed without the SQL termination character, the CLI client displays the "continuation prompt" (`...>` in your case) and expects the SQL command to be continued on the following line(s) until it is properly terminated.

See also *[Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)*.

Comment: @njachowski had an easier approach just ctrl-d

Comment: what if I mistakenly entered ":" in a statement? How do I stop the `...>` prompt?

Answer (score 62):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will get you out of the SQLite 3 database command prompt.

That is: hold the "Ctrl" button then press the lowercase *d* key on your keyboard at the same time and you will escape the SQLite 3 command prompt.

Comment: That works on Linux, but does it work on Windows?

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648652/exit-the-sqlite-shell-on-android/32660297#32660297) suggests it is Ctrl + Z on ***Windows***.

Comment: ctrl+d does not always clean exit a programme, e.g. when you use it on a background process in `bash`, in the `sqlite` case it does.

Comment: When connected via a web-shell (e.g. AWS EC2) Ctrl-D is not always a typeable key.

Answer (score 26):

### Tldr;

Use a `;` (semicolon) press enter then use `.exit`. Done!

### The invincible trap

You have entered **multiline command input**. To exit the command multiline input **use a semicaolon (`;`) to complete your command**. And then use `.exit` to exit from sqlite commandline or continue with what you want to do.

```bash
sqlite>
sqlite> cd
   ...>
   ...> .exit
   ...> .exit
   ...> exit()
   ...> ;  # This semicolon completes the incomplete cd command
Error: near "cd": syntax error
sqlite> .exit
```

[image: see the Example]

Comment: This is the best answer. working correctly for windows.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: the working code piece which needs to be copied is in text format. @ggorlen

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't change my link, which I'm not sure if you read. Images of text are a waste of bandwidth for people with limited data, can't be read by visually impaired users, can't be viewed as easily for people with small screens, and dozens of other reasons you can read about in the link. It's trivial to make this sort of thing text and would take you no more time to do than writing comments. If everyone's code in answers was like this, the site would be unusable.

Comment: by the way the amount of text you posted are consuming the resources of SO and user bandwidth more than the size of the image which is more meaningful and straight forward. This still doesn't justifies if problem can be solved easily should not be made complicated. Also, for screen readers and assisting devices description and explanation is still sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

You can terminate the SQLite 3 program by typing your system's [end-of-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) character (usually a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>). Use the interrupt character (usually a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) to stop a long-running SQL statement.

Answer (score 5):

For the Windows command prompt, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> worked for me. It directly brought me out of the `sqlite>` prompt.

If you want to stay at the `sqlite>` prompt, but just come out of the inner prompt, `...>`, then as JimmyB has said, type <kbd>;</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It just completes your statement, the prompt `...>` shows it is expecting more in the statement so far typed, as SQLite statements always end with a semicolon.

Comment: I know this is a year after, but using `CTRL` + `Z` should not be the correct usage as it just moves the current job (being `$ sqlite`) to the background instead of closing it like `CTRL` + `D` does. Try running `$ fg` after pressing `CTRL` + `Z` and you should be back at your sqlite prompt.

Comment: @Yuval Meshorer: But he said "[Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) command prompt". This may be different from [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux).

Answer (score 3):

To see all SQLite commands in the SQLite prompt, use the `.help` command. Before stucking at the command prompt, you can use the `.exit` command.

Comment: What do you mean by "stucking at"? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Running `.help .exit` shows

```
.exit ?CODE?             Exit this program with return-code CODE
```

With that said, running `.exit 0` exits it from sqlite3 console.

Alternatively, simply use `.quit` or `CTRL + D`