# Exit to shell after running a SQLite script in PowerShell

Tags: sqlite, powershell

For years (at least since 2004) I've developed databases using SQLite and running the scripts under the command prompt, like this:

```
sqlite3 mytest.db < mytest.sql > mytest.txt
```

This runs the script contained in `mytest.sql` and outputs to `mytest.txt`, and then returns back to the OS prompt. I can use a quick edit, test, and review cycle.

However, when I try the same with PowerShell, like this:

```
.\sqlite3 mytest.db -init mytest.sql > mytest.txt
```

I get stuck and have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to escape back to the prompt. Otherwise, it's just the same as in the command prompt.

I've tried the following in my SQL script:

1. `.exit` [SQLite dot command]
2. `.system Exit`
3. `.system Exit-PSSession`
4. `.system Exit-PSHostProcess`
5. piping the command (with `| Exit-PSHostProcess`)
6. using semicolon searated statements (with `; Exit-PSHostProcess`)

But nothing seems to work. Doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> isn't a big deal, but it's aggravating to have to do it. Is there a way to return to the PowerShell prompt after running the SQLite script?

Comment: Why did you add `-init`?

Comment: Why  did I add -init? PS apparently does not recognize < as the input redirection operator and I found a work around that uses -init.

Comment: Isn't Ctrl + D [the more standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747624/exit-a-sqlite3-database) to exit the interactive SQLite prompt? (I haven't tried it on Windows (yet).)

Answer (score 1):

I'm replying to a very old post, but well, I have the same problem and I just found the solution.

Maybe this will be useful for someone else :

```
sqlite3 .\mytest.db -init .\mytest.sql -batch .exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The input redirection `<` is reserved in powershell so it won't work. You have to do something like this:

```
gc .\mytest.sql | sqlite3.exe mytest.db > mytest.txt
```

After running the commands in `\mytest.sql` it will exit automatically